# Numeric input don't work in apriori in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, numeric, interactive

I have this code in ui.R:

```
tabPanel("Experiment 1",sidebarPanel(numericInput("supp", "Vložte hodnotu support", 0.0001, min = 0.0001, max = 0.8, step = 0.0001),
                        numericInput("conf", "Vložte hodnotu confidence", 0.0001, min = 0.0001, max = 0.8, step = 0.0001)),
```

and this code in server.R:

```
rules.all <- apriori(d, parameter=list(support=input$supp, confidence=input$conf))

library(arulesViz)

output$scatterPlot = renderPlot(
plot(rules.all, method = 'scatterplot')
)
```

I have this error:
When I change support and confidence values in numericInput, R shiny didn't display any scatter plot. Why didn't it work ? 
Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this few lines of code I can see that you try to access inputs from UI in a not reactive environment. It is not allowed and shiny yields an error. You have to create a reactive dataset (for instance `rules.all`) in which you should place

```
apriori(d, parameter=list(support=input$supp, confidence=input$conf))
```

The dataset will update each time you interact with a single widget and you can then access it in every `render*` Function with `rules.all()`

```
plot(rules.all(), method = 'scatterplot')
```

Since you didn't provide data I used an example dataset `Groceries` from the reference of `plot.rules`

```
library(shiny)
library(arulesViz)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   titlePanel(""),

     tabsetPanel(
       tabPanel("Experiment 1",
          sidebarPanel(
            # Changed values of the widgets
              numericInput("supp", "Vložte hodnotu support", 0.01, 
                           min = 0.01, max = 0.8, step = 0.01),
              numericInput("conf", "Vložte hodnotu confidence", 0.01, 
                           min = 0.01, max = 0.8, step = 0.01))
      )
     ), 
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("scatterPlot")
     )
  )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  ## You can't access inputs from UI in a not reactive environment. 
  ## rules.all <- apriori(d, parameter=list(support=input$supp, confidence=input$conf))

  data("Groceries")

  # Create a reactive dataset which you can access in all render* functions 
  # via rules.all()
  rules.all <- reactive({
    apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support=input$supp, confidence=input$conf))
  })

  output$scatterPlot = renderPlot({ 
    plot(rules.all(), method = 'scatterplot')
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score -1):

thanks a lot...but I must to do these operations behind apriori and then make a scatter plot on the screen:

```
quality(rules.all) <- round(quality(rules.all), digits=3)
```

`top.support <- sort(rules.all, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA, by = "support")`   `rules.sorted = sort(rules.all, by="lift")`

```
subset.matrix = is.subset(rules.sorted, rules.sorted)

subset.matrix[lower.tri(subset.matrix, diag=T)] = NA

redundant = colSums(subset.matrix, na.rm=T) >= 1

rules.pruned = rules.sorted[!redundant]

rules.all = rules.pruned

rules.sorted = sort(rules.all, by="lift") 

rules.all = rules.sorted
```

(my dataset for input to apriori is called "d")

what I must do with the code ?